# Как ассоциативный массив разбить на зависимые друг от друга select для выбора соответствующих значений?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

Есть ассоциативный объект на `php` значения которого представляют собой массивы

```
<?php

$colors = {
  "Black":[123],
  "White":[456, 678, 890],
  "Red":[731, 222],
  "Blue":[478, 888]
?>
```

Мне нужно поместить его значения в цепочку зависимых `select`, чтобы можно было организовать по ним форму поиска. Т.е. сделать так, чтобы при выборе цвета в первом `select` подгружались соответствующие этому элементу значения (при выборе Black во втором `select` были доступны для выбора 123, White - 456, 678, 890 и т.д.).

Застопорился на моменте кодирования и передаче объекта

```
json_encode($colors);
```

из `php` в `js`, - получаю *ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON*.
Как решить?

**Код**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var colors = JSON.parse(<?php echo $colors; ?>);

  $('#options').on('change', function() {

    var selectValue = $(this).val();

    $('#choices').empty();

    for (i = 0; i < colors[selectValue].length; i++) {

      $('#choices').append("<option value='" + colors[selectValue][i] + "'>" + colors[selectValue][i] + "</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <select id="options">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select id="choices">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select an option</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: нанчните с того, чтобы пхп код для массива написать в соответствии синтаксису языка.

Comment: потом сразу сгенерите целиком второй инпут. а в дата-атрибут опшенов впишите цвет. При сменен значений первого селекта просто скрывайте все кроме выбранного цвета по атрибуту во втором.

Comment: @teran массив написал в соответствии с синтаксисом, а вот из вашего описания ничего не понял, что предлагаете... Можете кодом изобразить для наглядности? Как уже писал выше: у меня проблема передачи объекта со значениями в виде массивов из `php` в `js` для последующего манипулирования, т.к. получаю ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы передаете в JSON.parse() не кодированную строку, а php массив.
`var colors = JSON.parse(<?php echo $colors; ?>);`

Вместо этого нужно.
`var colors = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($colors);?>);`

И проверьте в console.log(), чему равно colors.

Comment: вы, к сожалению, не внимательно прочитали описание задачи, т.к. я указывал, что при кодировании json_encode($colors); получаю ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON`, т.к. значения представляют из себя массивы, а не строки

Comment: @Вася а чему равен $colors в этой строке `var colors = JSON.parse(<?php echo $colors; ?>);`?